# How to use python superclass and inheritance (turtle graphics example)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, super, superclass

I've been playing around with turtle graphics, trying to better understand objects and I've encountered a little issue. I've learned about the super() function and wanted to use it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, _Screen, Screen    

class turtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape="circle")            

wn = Screen()
tortoise = turtle()
```

So if I do this, everything works like charm. I get a screen and I can use any Turtle method on my turtle class.

```
from turtle import Turtle, _Screen, Screen

class window(_Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup(500,500)
        self.screensize(1000,1000)
        self.title("Title")
        self.bgcolor("black")

wn = window()
```

This will also work great, I get what I ask: black window of 1000x1000 in a 500x500 box with slide bars. No problem. But, if I want to combine these:

```
from turtle import Turtle, _Screen, Screen

class window(_Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup(500,500)
        self.screensize(1000,1000)
        self.title("Title")
        self.bgcolor("black")

class turtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape="circle")

wn = window()
tortoise = turtle()
```

It will display the screen, but I will get an error from the turtle:

> AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute '_mode'

I have been looking through the turtle module and found that the Screen() function does this:

```
def Screen():
    """Return the singleton screen object.
    If none exists at the moment, create a new one and return it,
    else return the existing one."""
    if Turtle._screen is None:
        Turtle._screen = _Screen()
    return Turtle._screen
```

So I modified the window class to include this:

```
from turtle import Turtle, _Screen, Screen

class window(_Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        Turtle._screen = Screen()
        super().__init__()
        #self.setup(500,500)
        #self.screensize(1000,1000)
        #self.title("Title")
        #self.bgcolor("black")

class turtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape="circle")

wn = window()
tortoise = turtle()
```

It works like this, I will get a white window, with a round turtle. But if I uncomment the ***setup***, the ***screensize*** or the ***bgcolor*** part, I will get an error:

> AttributeError: 'window' object has no attribute '_tracing'

or

> AttributeError: 'window' object has no attribute 'cv'

So I would again have to declare some parameters before the ***__init__*** in the ***window*** class, to make it work. It seems there is something I'm missing. Why does the turtle inherit everything and works great, but the ***_Screen*** is not initializing with all it's necessary parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, the turtle `Screen` is an onion of many layers.  There are two issues we need to address: the `_Screen` class invokes it's super's (TurtleScreen's) initializer in a way that isn't subclass friendly; the `Screen()` function is called from lots of places and it hardcodes which class creates the screen.  So let's address both issues:

```
import turtle

class MyScreen(turtle._Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        turtle.TurtleScreen.__init__(self, MyScreen._canvas)

        self.setup(500, 500)
        self.screensize(1000, 1000)
        self.title("Title")
        self.bgcolor("black")

def MyScreenFunction():
    if turtle.Turtle._screen is None:
        turtle.Turtle._screen = MyScreen()
    return turtle.Turtle._screen

turtle.Screen = MyScreenFunction

class MyTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape="circle")

wn = turtle.Screen()

tortoise = MyTurtle()
tortoise.color('white')

tortoise.circle(100)

wn.mainloop()
```

However, there may be a better way to go.  Turtle can be used both *standalone* as above, and *embedded* in a tkinter program.  The *embedded* approach uses `RawTurtle`, `TurtleScreen` and optionally `Scrolled Canvas`.  These classes may be easier to subclass and the better approach might be to build your own equivalent of standalone turtle through embedding turtle in tkinter and subclassing as needed.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. You said the TurtleScreen initializer is called in an unfriendly manner for subclass use, could you please expand a little on that? TurtleScreen.__init__(self, _Screen._canvas): is it because of the _Screen._canvas part? Should have been self._canvas maybe?

Comment: @BogdanPrădatu, the initializer call to the parent of `_Screen` is done in the old Python 2 style instead of a Python 3 call to `super()`.  The old style call has information about the object heirarchy hardcoded into it.  The new style fixes this.  Also, part of the problem may be trying to subclass *standalone* turtle so I've added a brief discussion of that to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After cdlane's answer, I found out that I could make it a little simpler. The `Screen()` part could be introduced in the `__init__` function:

```
from turtle import Turtle, TurtleScreen, _Screen

class window(_Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        TurtleScreen.__init__(self, window._canvas)
        if Turtle._screen is None:
            Turtle._screen = self
        self.setup(500,500)
        self.screensize(1000,1000)
        self.title("Title")
        self.bgcolor("black")

class turtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(shape="circle")
        self.color("white")
        self.speed(0)
        self.circle(50)

wn = window()
tortoise = turtle()
```

Thanks again, mate!